# Cannot send HTML string through axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, quill

I'm working on a blog like website and have being adding this rich text editor feature to it. This app is built with Vue for the front and Laravel, and this text editor is a dependency called vue-quill.

I use axios to post all the data and nothing more. Im using it to create posts with Raw html tags from this editor, it actually works fine creating and updating posts locally, but only fails on my server whenever you try to update any post, it returns empty response and status 200.

It does not happen when you create a post. Im not using any kind of image upload service but I'm using my own solution, which consists on transforming images from base 64 to file objects and then send them to a controller via axios. On update action it is similar but the images that were already uploaded on the post are fetched, then converted to base64 again and then converted to file objects again (in order to preserve previous images) for new images I convert them from base64 to file object as I do on my create action.

Here is the code I use to create from base 64 to file object :

```
dataURLtoFile(dataurl, filename) {
  let arr = dataurl.split(','), mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
  bstr = atob(arr[1]), n = bstr.length, u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
    while(n--){
      u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
    }
    return new File([u8arr], filename, {type:mime});
}
```

And this would be my axios action:

```
  axios
    .post("/api/posts", formData, {
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    })
    .then((response)=>{
      this.submit = false;
      this.title= '';
      this.showAlert("success", 'Post created successfully.' , '')
    })
    .catch((error) =>{
     // etc
    });
```

The formData object only store the raw html, images and a string, nothing more than that, but I'm not sure if the headers of the axios are ok, the laravel  action is like this:

```
public function updatePost(Request $request)
{ 

    $request->validate([
        'files.*' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:2048'
    ]);
        
    $post = Post::find($request->postId);
    $images = $request->file('files'); 
    // creamos el post primero
    $post->title = $request->title;
    $post->body = $request->body;
    $post->save();
    // the rest of the code for storing images
    return response()->json(['post' => $post]);
```

I think something is preventing it to reach to this action, because the response is empty.

Edit: I had a problem later where the request was giving status 301, after searching here and there I found out that everything was okay but in the server. The host has to be configured as stated here in this quick guide for 301 troubles : https://medium.com/@mshanak/laravel-return-empty-response-690f8a308d9a.

Comment: Have you tried checking if you reach the end of the `updatePost` function? If so, maybe `console.log(response)` after your Axios call to see what's returned.

Comment: I just tested what you said, It never reaches the controller. console.log of response shows this object just as would expect, but data is empty, I could not tell if the other properties are fine, but the seem to be that way.

Comment: It's weird that it is not reaching your controller actually. You'll surely get an empty response if the controller is not reached. Try checking if your route is defined in your routing file (web.php or api.php). Also, check in your browser's developer console if the call triggers an error in the Network tab.

Comment: A helper library like [Vue API Query](https://github.com/robsontenorio/vue-api-query/) may help you here, provided you have a RESTful API. This merely avoids the problem but having a middleware to make API calls work automagically can help in the future as well.

Comment: Hi there, I solved it already. It was a server host configuration problem, I had to add some rules for my httpaccess of apache, it seems to be very recurrent issue on laravel deployments, thanks anyway.